# Powershell-Azure WebApp IpRestrictions - WebApps Array

Tags: arrays, azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I have been struggling to come up with a working solution for days on this

**What am I trying to achieve?**

```
Foreach ($item in $webApps){ 
$WebAppConfig = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $item -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ApiVersion $APIVersion) 
}
```

**The issue is that "-resourceName" will not accept objects, but rather only a string**

I am looking for a way to take the output of the following command, convert it to a string, so that it can satisfy  –ResourceName, and loop through each item in the string

```
$webApps = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup | Get-AzureRmWebApp).name
```

This returns a nice list of Azure WebApps that exist in a specified ResourceGroup, however they are in object form, which –ResourceName will not take

I have tried several ways to convert the output of $webApps to a string, add a comma to the end, then do a –split ','  but nothing seems to work for properly, where –ResourceName will accept it

**Method 1:**

```
[string]$webAppsArrays =@() 

Foreach ($webApp in $webApps){ 

$webAp+',' -split ',' 

}
```

**Method 2:**

$

```
webApps | ForEach-Object { 

$webApp = $_ + "," 

Write-Host $webApp 

}
```

**Method 3:**

```
$csvPath2 = 'C:\Users\Giann\Documents\_Git Repositorys\QueriedAppList2.csv' 

$webApps = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup | Get-AzureRmWebApp).name | out-file -FilePath $csvPath1 -Append 

$csvFile2 = import-csv -Path $csvPath1 -Header Name
```

This ouputs a list in a CSV, however these are still objects, so I cannot pass each item into –ResourceName

I am going in circles trying to make the below a repeatable, looping script

**The desired end result would be to use the below script, with an array of webApps, being queried from the provided resource group variable:**

Any help would be greatly appreciated for how to use this script, but pull a dynamic list of WebApps from a specified Resource Group, keeping in mind the -ResourceName "String" restrictions in the $WebAppConfig variable

**Here is the original script to create IP Restrictions for 1 Web App and 1 Resource Group, using properties from a CSV file:**

```
#Create a Function to create IP Restrictions for 1 Web App and 1 Resource Group, using properties from the CSV file:  

#Variables 
$WebApp = "" 
$resourceGroup ="" 
$subscription_Id = '' 

#Login to Azure 
Remove-AzureRmAccount -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null 
Login-AzureRmAccount -EnvironmentName AzureUSGovernment -Subscription $subscription_Id 

Function CreateIpRestriction {  
Param (  
[string] $name,  
[string] $ipAddress,  
[string] $subnetMask,  
[string] $action,  
[string] $priority  
)  

$APIVersion = ((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq sites).ApiVersions[0]  

$WebAppConfig = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $WebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ApiVersion $APIVersion)  

$ipRestriction = $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions  
$ipRestriction.name = $name  
$ipRestriction.ipAddress = $ipAddress  
$ipRestriction.subnetMask = $subnetMask  
$ipRestriction.action = $action  
$ipRestriction.priority = $priority  
return $ipRestriction  
}  

#Set csv file path:  
$csvPath5 = 'C:\Users\Giann\Documents\_Git Repositorys\ipRestrictions5.csv' 

#import CSV Contents  
$ipRestrictionArray = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath5  

$ipRestrictions = @()  
foreach($item in $ipRestrictionArray){  
Write-Host "Adding ipRestriction properties for" $item.name  
$newIpRestriction = CreateIpRestriction -name $item.name -ipAddress $item.ipAddress -subnetMask $item.subnetMask -action $item.action -priority $item.priority  
$ipRestrictions += $newIpRestriction  
}  

#Set the new ipRestriction on the WebApp 
Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $WebApp/web -ApiVersion $APIVersion -PropertyObject $ipRestrictions
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the Resource names using this: `$ResourceNames = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup | Get-AzureRmWebApp | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`? Or as per your first code block using: 
`$webApps | ForEach-Object { $WebAppConfig = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ApiVersion $APIVersion) }` ?

Comment: Thank you!  Using your input, I was able to come up with 2 methods that seem to be working:  # Method 1
$webApps | ForEach-Object {
    $WebAppConfig = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $webApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ApiVersion $APIVersion)
}

#Method 2
$WebAppConfig = $webApps | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $webApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ApiVersion $APIVersion)
  }

Comment: My new issue is that when I run:  Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $WebApp/web -ApiVersion $APIVersion -PropertyObject $ipRestrictions,  it errors "The property 'name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set." and does this for each property I set "name, ipAddress, action, priority: in my posted script

Comment: I have confirmed that ipSecurityProperties has "name, ipAddress, priority, action" via the Json example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions  Any idea why after setting all of the properties in my script, it claims these properties do not exist for: $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions

Comment: This is in reference to the section of my script:   $ipRestriction = $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions  
$ipRestriction.name = $name  
$ipRestriction.ipAddress = $ipAddress  
$ipRestriction.subnetMask = $subnetMask  
$ipRestriction.action = $action  
$ipRestriction.priority = $priority  
return $ipRestriction  
}

Comment: Shouldn't you just use `$WebApp` instead of `$WebApp/web`? If `/web` is part of the name, surround it with double quotes like `"$WebApp/web"`

Comment: This errors actually occur before I run the Set-AzureRmResource. It's when I run:                                                                                                                         $ipRestrictions = @() 
 foreach($item in $ipRestrictionArray){
Write-Host "Adding ipRestriction properties for" $item.name
 $newIpRestriction = CreateIpRestriction -name $item.name -ipAddress $item.ipAddress -subnetMask $item.subnetMask -action $item.action -priority $item.priority
 $ipRestrictions += $newIpRestriction
 } Those properties are in .Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions

Comment: Ok, I think then you should show us your `CreateIpRestriction` function because it looks like it is not returning an proper PSObject the `Set-AzureRmResource` cmdlet wants for the `-PropertyObject` (alias for `-Properties`) parameter.

Comment: My original post has the script, with the function in it. I create parameters, which are then passed via a csv that has each property

Comment: I think you're over doing it there. The `Set-AzureRmResource` wants a PSObject with just 5 properties. You are creating an obect `$ipRestriction = $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions`

Comment: Hmm so I cannot create the psobject, then feed the object properties via a csv, shown in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As continuation on the comments, I really need multiline, so here as an answer.

> **Note that I cannot test this myself**

This page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/set-azurermresource?view=azurermps-6.11.0#optional-parameters) shows that the `Set-AzureRmResource` **-Properties** parameter should be of type `PSObject`.
*(instead of `-Properties` you may also use the alias `-PropertyObject`)*

In your code, I don't think the function `CreateIpRestriction` returns a PSObject but tries to do too much.

Anyway, try like this:

```
Function CreateIpRestriction {  
    Param (  
        [string] $name,  
        [string] $ipAddress,  
        [string] $subnetMask,  
        [string] $action,  
        [string] $priority  
    )  
    # There are many ways to create a PSObject (or PSCustomObject if you like).  
    # Have a look at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7804.powershell-creating-custom-objects.aspx for instance.
    return New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            name = $name  
            ipAddress = $ipAddress  
            subnetMask = $subnetMask  
            action = $action  
            priority = $priority
        }
}

#Set csv file path:  
$csvPath5 = 'C:\Users\Giann\Documents\_Git Repositorys\ipRestrictions5.csv' 

#import CSV Contents  
$ipRestrictionArray = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath5  

# create an new array of IP restrictions (PSObjects)
$newIpRestrictions = @()  
foreach($item in $ipRestrictionArray){  
    Write-Host "Adding ipRestriction properties for" $item.name  
    $newIpRestrictions += (CreateIpRestriction -name $item.name -ipAddress $item.ipAddress -subnetMask $item.subnetMask -action $item.action -priority $item.priority  )
}  

# here we set the restrictions we collected in $newIpRestrictions in the $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions array
$APIVersion = ((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq sites).ApiVersions[0]  
$WebAppConfig = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $WebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ApiVersion $APIVersion)  
$WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions = $newIpRestrictions
$WebAppConfig | Set-AzureRmResource -ApiVersion $APIVersion -Force | Out-Null
```

The code above will **replace** the `ipSecurityRestrictions` by a new set. You may want to consider first getting them and adding to the already existing list.

I found examples for Getting, Adding and Removing ipSecurityRestrictions [here](https://moimhossain.com/2018/07/31/azure-web-app-removing-ip-restrictions/), but I can imagine there are more examples to be found.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much. Been spinning my wheels for days. So many small things, that achieve the same thing, and syntax is kiling it. Now i am going to try and use this working script, to query all apps within a specified resouregroup, and set ipRestrictions for all the Web Apps